# log4j - create multiple files on the fly

Tags: java, filter, log4j

Imagine I'm creating an application to manage employees of a company and, appart from the main application log, I want to maintain one log file for the actions associated with each employee. So, every time I create a new object Employee, a new log file should be created and log entries should be picked up with (for example) simple string matching.

To put it simply, the content of the log file for emplyee 5 should be equivalent to the output of:

```
$ grep "EmployeeId=5" application.log
```

What is the easiest way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure log4j on the fly. This is where you associate a specific logger name with the file that you want it to output to. Here is an article on that subject: http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html

Then you also have to create a logger for each of your employees. You can keep these loggers in a hashmap so that you can access them dynamically at runtime. Just use Logger.getLogger("Employee"+x) to create the logger.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use log4j or any debug logging framework for this. Just open a file and write the output you want to it. File f = new File("outputdir/"+employee.id)

Answer (score 0):

Log4J does not allow you to dynamically create 'undefined' log files.  All log files need to be predefined (either in log4j.xml or a properties file).

You could investigate using the MDC or NDC context.  This allows you to associate a context with your logging which can be useful in some cases:

[Log4j MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)

If using an MDC context is not enough I can only say that I think you will have to implement a log writer yourself.  (Be careful with concurrency and performance.)